# Tableau - capturing the value of a reference line in another sheet

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dot plot that I created to view test results of a population of subjects. In the dot plot I created dynamic reference lines so the user can set the upper and lower percentiles they want to view. I would like to create a calculated field to capture the value of the reference line. For example, if the user chooses "Target A1" and sets the lower reference line to 20th percentile, I'd like to create a calculated field to show the value of the 20th percentile reference line (59.8) in another sheet.

The end goal is to be able to capture the samples that fall within a given percentile range based on the reference line values. It seems simple enough but may be beyond the scope of my understanding. Is this possible to accomplish?

Thanks in advance!